# An action anime featuring guns about a boy and a girl who resolves a bus hijacking incident in one of the episodes

Tags: hidan-no-aria

I remember watching a few episodes of this anime, which was an action anime that featured guns.

In one of the episodes, the two protagonists (a male with black hair, and a blonde female, both teens I believe) were stuck on a hijacked bus along with many other people. The two protagonist had communication with some sort of headquarters. I believe there was a threat to the bus saying that if the bus were to slow down or stop, it would get blown up. Therefore, the bus driver couldn't slow down and had to go faster and faster, and when the bus was approaching a corner, they weren't able to turn. However, the two teens thought of gathering all people onto one side of the bus and using their weight to make the bus lean and turn.

In another episode, I think the two teens were on their way to school, but they got stopped half way at a warehouse as a bunch of robots came out of somewhere and started shooting at them. The teens decided to hide behind crates/boxes. They then pulled out their guns (which they were **very** good at using) and started shooting at the robots, but it wasn't really effective. There and then, I think it was the male character who did something and shot **all** the robots right in the robot's muzzle, which made all of the robots exploded, creating a scene for the two teens to escape

In yet another episode (and the last one I can remember), they were on a plane and they found out that one of their friends had been sabotaging them. Some intense talking went down, and that friend of theirs decided to jump out of the plane (safely, because that friend planned the whole thing, so she somehow had a parachute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like [**Hidan no Aria**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aria_the_Scarlet_Ammo) (English title: *Aria The Scarlet Ammo*), except that the girl (**Kanzaki H. Aria**) has pink hair instead of blonde hair (her hair was originally blonde, though). Both of the protagonists are adept with guns, since they are students at Tokyo Butei High, where students are trained to become Butei (*Armed Detective*).

Episode 3 of the series features a bus hijacking incident, where the bus would be blown up if it were to slow down or stop. *However, the part about leaning the bus with the weight of all the people on the bus does not occur in this series. Also, they were not stuck on the bus from the beginning, but they actually took on the mission to rescue everyone on the bus. They did get on the bus to search for the bomb, though.*

The second half of episode 1 of the series features a scene where the two protagonists were inside a vaulting box inside a warehouse, when some remote controlled Segway mounted with guns came and shot at them. The male protagonist Tōyama Kinji (after activating *Hysteria Mode*, a special condition that runs in his family) shot into the muzzles of all the guns, causing all of them to explode.

Episode 4 and 5 is where the two protagonists found out that **Mine Riko**, one of their friends at school, was actually the culprit behind the previous incidents in episode 1 and 3. They had a few shootouts in the plane, and Riko escape from the plane by opening a hole on side of the plane with explosives and turning her clothes into a parachute.